# ng-model for select with defined options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a plain **select control** in my angular app. When page loads I've got no element selected in **select control** but if I check *$scope.data.Method* I've got a correct value in int. Is there any way to fix this issue?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Selected Method:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="data.Method">
            <option value="0">Auction</option>
            <option value="1">Delivery</option>
            <option value="2">Range Delivery</option>
            <option value="3">Broadcast</option>
            <option value="4">Self broadcast</option>
            <option value="5">Manual</option>
            <option value="6">Automated</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controlers use service to get data. Here is service code for getting data

```
//Initialize Resource
        this.initResource = function (params) {
            params = params || {};
            params.id = '@id';

            this.resource = $resource('{0}/:id'.format(this.api), params, {
                'update': { method: 'POST' },
                'create': { method: 'PUT' },
                'default': { method: 'GET', params: { id: 'default' } }
            });
        }
//...more code
//Get some data and initialize additional parameters
        this.read = function (id, clone, readonly, version) {
            if (clone == undefined)
                clone = false;

            if (readonly == undefined)
                readonly = false;

            if (this.resource == null) {
                this.initResourceByDefault();
            }

            return this.resource.get({ id: id, clone: clone, readonly: readonly, version: version });
        }
```

Controller code

```
function ItemController($scope, $route, $routeParams, $location, $resource, MainCRUDService, ControllerHelper) {
    $scope.noticeType = $routeParams.noticeType;

    MainCRUDService.initResource({ noticeType: $scope.noticeType });
    //Here I am getting data from resourse via service  
    ControllerHelper.initCRUD($scope, MainCRUDService);
}
```

Comment: Give controller code how you are initializing it

Comment: Added code in post

Comment: i asked you for controller code not service code.

Comment: The problem is the place where you are initializing model value in controller.

Comment: added a controller code too.

Comment: Buddy you are not understanding i want only the specific code where you are initializing $scope.data.Method = initializationValue;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can understand your problem, your service is returning `data.Method` as an integer value.

But select box will match a string value.

Your problem will get solved if your service will return `data.Method` as string. Also you can convert your response paramter `data.Method` to a string value, by using `toString()` method.

Here is a plunker code which may help you.
https://plnkr.co/edit/s0Wrk4?p=preview